# Advanced serializing django models

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have these django models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ts = models.CharField(max_length=25, editable=False)
    update_id = models.IntegerField( null=False)
    msg_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, blank=True)
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(ChatUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
    edited_version = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and serializer:

```
class UpdatesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('ts', 'update_id', 'msg_id', 'chat', 'user_id', 'text')
```

in views:

```
def get(self, request):
    updates = Event.objects.all()
    updates = [UpdatesSerializer().to_representation(update) for update in updates]

    return Response(updates)
```

it represents data like this:

```
{
        "ts": 1,
        "update_id": 4,
        "msg_id": 1,
        "chat": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "text": "test"
    }
```

How can I represent data like this? :

```
{
        "ts": 1,
        "update_id": 4,
        "details":{
            "msg_id": 1,
            "chat": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "text": "test"
                  }
    }
```

Actually I could separate this model and use fields from details as manytomany but it doesnt let me create event using this:

```
message_ = Event.objects.create(ts=int(time.time()), update_id=4)
message_.save()
message_.message.add(text="1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-define your serializers as below:

```
class DetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('msg_id', 'chat', 'user_id', 'text')


class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    details = DetailsSerializer(source='*')

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('ts', 'update_id', 'details')
```

and change `view` to

```
def get(self, request):
    event_queryset = Event.objects.all()
    event_serializer = EventSerializer(event_queryset, many=True)
    return Response(data = event_serializer.data)
```

You could add `text` like

```
message_ = Event.objects.create(ts=int(time.time()), update_id=4)

<strike>message_.save()</strike> #  this save is not required because the ".create()" method calls the save() method silently
message_.text = "some text i want to update"
message_.save() # this time save is mandatory because we changed the value and we have to save it to DB
```

**References**:

1. [`source` in DRF Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)
2. [DRF Nested Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example)

Comment: @marc_s I think bolding some code lines would help others to see/understand the difference. I think you are removing the *code* tags **blindly**. Why?

Comment: If you properly format your code, it will be syntax-highlighted - the bolding doesn't work in this case, therefore I removed it. Also: you get the proper formatting when just indenting your code by four spaces - you'll not get it with the `<code>` tags....

Comment: I'm using `<pre>` tag along with `<code>`. It surely does the formatting